# JavaScript Updating arrays with data from separate array

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I have two arrays both consisting of 30 items.
Array 1: [ {cat, red} , {dog, blue} , ... ]
Array 2: [ {1}, {2}, ... ]

My goal is to have Array 3 like so:
[ {Cat, red, 1} , {dog, blue, 2} ... ]
I am using JavaScript and cheerio to grab the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your objects look strange, `{1}` isn't a valid object. Maybe you meant something like `{id: 1}`?

Anyway, looks like you need something like this:

```
const arr3 = arr1.map((el, index) => {
  return {
    ...el,
    ...arr2[index],
  }
})
```

Comment: sorry about that I was struggling to explain the problem I was having so just dotted them down. arr1 = [ {title: 'movieA', rank: '1' }, {title: 'MovieB', rank: '2'}, ... ]  arr2= [{score: 10}, {score: 20} ... ]          I am about to try both solutions posted and unfortunately I cannot upvote them but I really appreciate the feedback

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what the data actually looks like, since  `[ {cat, red} , {dog, blue} , ... ]` isn't valid JSON or anything, but the general idea would be to get the corresponding element from the other array by index, either using `.map((el, index) => { // ... })` or just looping over it, so something like:

```js
const arr1 = [{title: 'movieA', rank: '1' }, {title: 'MovieB', rank: '2'}]
const arr2 = [{score: 10}, {score: 20}]

console.log(arr1.map((el, i) => {
    return { ...el, ...arr2[i] }
}));
```

Comment: sorry about that I was struggling to explain the problem I was having so just dotted them down. arr1 = [ {title: 'movieA', rank: '1' }, {title: 'MovieB', rank: '2'}, ... ]  arr2= [{score: 10}, {score: 20} ... ]          I am about to try both solutions posted and unfortunately I cannot upvote them but I really appreciate the feedback

Comment: ok see edit, I think I see what you are going for

Comment: thanks again Dave, is there a certain term I should have been looking up for this answer? Everything I searched for was just pushing the arrays together but losing structure.

Comment: I probably would have searched for "merge two arrays of objects by index"